# regular expression search using rubygem gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gmail

I am using ruby gem GMAIL to implement mail search functionality in my application. I face some duplication of search-result. Example

```
gmail.inbox.find(:body=>"java")
```

which includes the mails with body "javascript" also in to the search result, that I dont want to get.
Is there any way to search gmail body with some regular expressions.like

```
/\b(?:java)\b/
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **search** alias for this gem?  I can't test the code for you now but I am guessing it should allow keyword search.

Comment: find,search and mails,  all are giving same result.

Comment: In that case, I am guessing you will have to extract all the emails having "java" and apply your own Regex.